# Apex Sql Complete Locks Up SSMS

Tags: ssms-2016

I recently installed the latest version of Apex Complete on SSMS 2016. When I installed it, ssms would not start. It would open the window and get to the point where you normally be greeted with the prompt to connect to a db server, but would not open that prompt and not respond. Also the memory usage went up close to 1GB for SSMS. I then uninstalled the Apex Complete application and everything is working as it should.

I do have RedGate Sql Source control installed in SSMS, and I am curious if that could be the issue. Has anyone else ran into this issue? As I hadn't even connected to the db server, it shouldn't have any work to do at that point as far as parsing databases, so I'm not sure what the issue may be.

Comment: I would prefer to use RedGate Sql Prompt, but can't get my company to eat that expense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Support Engineer at Apex Sql:

I’d suggest that you perform a few steps to install a clean copy (remove leftovers) of ApexSQL Complete as it might solve the issue. Before you start, all running instances of SSMS and VS *must* be closed:

1. Uninstall ApexSQL Complete from Program and Features in Control Panel
2. Go to this location: %SystemDrive%\Program Files\ApexSQL and, if exists, delete the ApexSQL Complete folder
3. Go to this location: %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\ApexSQL and delete the ApexSQL Complete and ApexSQLAddinsLogs folders

After the 3rd step, download and install ApexSQL Complete from this link.

With this, my system is now working, but I do have a battle between the ssms code completion and the Apex, which I never had to deal with using the RedGate tools.